# Php, is it OK to use traits for DI?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, traits

consider this example:

```
class MyClass
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        $this->injected->getIt();
    }
}
```

so far so simple (apart from `injected` is not injected). So, in full version:

```
class MyClass
{
    /**
     * @var Injected
     */
    private $injected;

    public function __constructor(Injected $injected)
    {
        $this->injected = $injected;
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        $this->injected->getIt();
    }
}
```

but I find it enoromous. Why to pollute my class with tons of code of DI? Lets split this into two entities:

```
trait MyClassTrait
{
    /**
     * @var Injected
     */
    private $injected;

    public function __constructor(Injected $injected)
    {
        $this->injected = $injected;
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    use MyClassTrait;

    public function doSomething()
    {
        $this->injected->getIt();
    }
}
```

its much nicer although I never seen anybody using it like this. Is it a good approach?

Comment: Within one week you will open `MyClass` and then you'll ask yourself "what the heck is `injected`?". Is there a good reason to do that? You just hide your dependencies. You'll have 100 classes and 100 traits for which reason? That's not nice

Comment: imo factory + reflection is better way

Comment: @Kazz exactly how?

Comment: Since you cannot compose several different constructors/dependencies from several different traits, this is only useful if the exact same dependency set is used in several classes and there's nothing else to be done in the constructor. Otherwise you're writing one trait per class, which is actually more code than if you wrote the constructor directly into the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example like this:

```
<?php

class Factory
{
    private $services = [];

    public function __construct() {
        $this->services[self::class] = $this;
    }

    public function getByType($type){
        if(isset($services[$type])){
            return $services[$type];
        }

        if(class_exists($type)){
            $reflection = new ReflectionClass($type);
            $constructor = $reflection->getConstructor();

            $parameters = [];
            if($constructor)
            foreach($constructor->getParameters() as $parameter){
                if($parameter->getClass()) {
                    $parameters[] = $this->getByType($parameter->getClass()->name);
                } else if($parameter->isDefaultValueAvailable()){
                    $parameters[] = $parameter->getDefaultValue();
                }
            }

            return $services[$type] = $reflection->newInstanceArgs($parameters);
        } // else throw Exception...
    }
}

abstract class DI
{        
    public function __construct(Factory $factory) {           
        $reflection = new ReflectionClass(get_class($this));
        foreach($reflection->getProperties() as $property){
            preg_match('/@var ([^ ]+) @inject/', $property->getDocComment(), $annotation);
            if($annotation){
                $className = $annotation[1];
                if(class_exists($className)){
                    $property->setAccessible(true);
                    $property->setValue($this, $factory->getByType($className));
                } // else throw Exception...
            }
        }
    }
}

class Injected
{
    public function getIt($string){
        echo $string.'<br />';
    }
}


class DIByConstructor
{
    /** @var Injected */
    private $byConstructor;

    public function __construct(Injected $injected) {
        $this->byConstructor = $injected;
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        echo 'Class: '.self::class.'<br />';
        $this->byConstructor->getIt('By Constructor');
        echo '<br />';
    }      
}

class DIByAnnotation extends DI
{
    /** @var Injected @inject */
    private $byAnnotation;

    public function doSomething()
    {
        echo 'Class: '.self::class.'<br />';
        $this->byAnnotation->getIt('By Annotation');
        echo '<br />';
    }      
}

class DIBothMethods extends DI
{
    /** @var Injected */
    private $byConstructor;

    /** @var Injected @inject */
    private $byAnnotation;

    public function __construct(Factory $factory, Injected $injected) {
        parent::__construct($factory);
        $this->byConstructor = $injected;
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        echo 'Class: '.self::class.'<br />';
        $this->byConstructor->getIt('By Constructor');
        $this->byAnnotation->getIt('By Annotation');
        echo '<br />';
    }      
}

$factory = new Factory();

$DIByConstructor = $factory->getByType('DIByConstructor');
$DIByConstructor->doSomething();

$DIByAnnotation = $factory->getByType('DIByAnnotation');
$DIByAnnotation->doSomething();

$DIBothMethods = $factory->getByType('DIBothMethods');
$DIBothMethods->doSomething();
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that with @Kazz approaching (DI by Annotations) you cannot reference an Interface, instead you are referencing a Class. So this is good for fast instantiating with almost zero verbose but at the end, you are loosing all the DI potential.